# What is the energetic costs in KJ/g NH3 for nitrogenase fixation

Tags: metabolism, bioenergetics, energy-metabolism, nitrogen-cycle

What is the energetic costs in KJ/g NH<sub>3</sub> for nitrogenase fixation.

I want to compare Haber-Bosch vs nitrogenase.

How would I force the biological stochiometry of 8e- electrons into an energy quantity.

$N_2 + 8e^- + 8H^+ + 16ATP + 16H_2O → 2NH_3 + H_2 + 16ADP + 16P_i$

Comment: Well if your equation is correct and complete (I haven’t checked) I would start  with 8 x the standard free energy  of hydrolysis of ATP to ADP to get part of the answer in molar terms. But the equation is incomplete in so far as the donor of the reducing electrons is not specified so the redox change should be found for the half reaction, and then converted to a free energy change. This is all in a chapter in Berg, which you can find on NCBI Bookshelf. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Will check thank you for the resource